# How to mount glusterfs based san lun on another server and mount with ext4/xfs filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, glusterfs, glusterfs-3.5

I have one glusterfs based filesystem san lun with some data assigned to linux server and want to access that data on that server.

What are the possible ways to recover that data?

Tried to mount it but not mounted.

```
 [root@node-slave4 ~]# mount -t glusterfs /dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04 /mnt/
 Mounting glusterfs on /mnt failed.
 [root@node-slave4 ~]# mount -t gfs2 /dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04 /mnt/
 mount: mount /dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04 on /mnt failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I have tried to create gluster volume as well however it's not mounted on server because mount point is not created due to above error.

```
[root@node-slave4 ~]# gluster volume create volume1 node-slave4:/dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04 flume:/dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04  force
volume create: volume1: failed: The provided path /dev/mapper/chep_vg04-chep_lv04 which is already present, is not a directory
```